# How to get content from another domain

Tags: php, jquery, xml, curl, rss

I'm currently working on a new backpacker trip portal. My idea is to load specific trip warnings from the official governement site on my site. I am allowed to use their official information due to german laws.
But the point is, that they change their content on a daily to hourly basis, so copy & paste is no solution. I already tried getting their content via jQuery, but cross-domain-policy came across and as you can imagine I have no control over their server ;-)
While searching for a solution I came across cURL in PHP. From here on I need your help, because I can only wright some few small functions. I thought maybe there is an option to fetch the content via cURL and then just display the divs I need or to use their rss feed and fetch the information from there?
Any help or hints are appreciated :-)

Website: http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/WeitereAktuelleReiseInformationen_node.html
xml-based rss feed: http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/SiteGlobals/Functions/RSSFeed/DE/RSSNewsfeed/RSS_Reisehinweise.xml?nn=332604

Comment: You could use curl or fopen or file_get_contents...from there all you need is a way to parse the XML which, lucky for you, is quite easy in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML Solution [Simple html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is a library that permit use select DOM tag type jquery,

use like as

```
$html=file_get_html('http://www.auswaertigesamt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/WeitereAktuelleReiseInormationen_node.html');

$note_text = $html->find("div[class=reiseUebersicht]", 0)->children(1)->plaintext;
```

I guess that HTML is a easy solution because your RSS(xml) is unlike a standard  because it embed html , like as "`<![CDATA[ ]]>`"

Parse XML Solution use [PHP Simple DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906366/parsing-an-rss-feed-in-php-with-dom), but you need parse HML DOM , for decode cdata

$doc = DOMDocument::load('http://www.example.com/file.xml');