# Parse json object with empty name

Tags: php, json

This is the response json I am getting.Please help to parse the json.I used json_decode ,but i don't know how to deal with an object with no name.

```
   {
        "child": {
            "": {
                "rss": [{
                    "data": "\n \n",
                    "attribs": {
                        "": {
                            "version": "2.0"
                        }
                    },
                    "xml_base": "",
                    "xml_base_explicit": false,
                    "xml_lang": "",
                    "child": {
                        "": {
                            "channel": [{
                                "data": "\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n ",
                                "attribs": [],
                                "xml_base": "",
                                "xml_base_explicit": false,
                                "xml_lang": "",
                                "child": {
                                    "": {
                                        "title": [{
                                            "data": "Data name",
                                            "attribs": [],
                                            "xml_base": "",
                                            "xml_base_explicit": false,
                                            "xml_lang": ""
                                        }]
                                    }

                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to fetch the value of data inside title.But I dont know to how to solve an object with no name.Can someone please help.

```
 {
        "child": {
            "": {}}}
```

Comment: have you tried the code before? if yes, post it here.

Comment: There was other outer loops .I reached here by using forloop.But I dont know how to move forward. @david

Comment: Where do you get that json from? It would be easier to fix that.

Comment: Let me guess - is this some XML to array output.  If you stick with using XML there are all sorts of resources for that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906366/parsing-an-rss-feed-in-php-with-dom, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to access the `title` object, dependent on whether you decode the JSON as an object or as an array. If you decode as an object, you need to use the `->{'element'}` notation to get around the empty names (**Note** this **only** works in PHP 7.2 and higher):

```
$json = json_decode($jsonstr);
print_r($json->child->{''}->rss[0]->child->{''}->channel[0]->child->{''}->title);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object (
         [data] => Data name
         [attribs] => Array ( )
         [xml_base] =>
         [xml_base_explicit] =>
         [xml_lang] => 
    )
)
```

As an array you just need to use a blank index (`''`):

```
$json = json_decode($jsonstr, true);
print_r($json['child']['']['rss'][0]['child']['']['channel'][0]['child']['']['title']);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [data] => Data name
        [attribs] => Array ( )
        [xml_base] =>
        [xml_base_explicit] =>
        [xml_lang] =>
    ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kh37Y)

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps;

```
<?php
$json='{
        "child": {
            "": {
                "rss": [{
                    "data": "\n \n",
                    "attribs": {
                        "": {
                            "version": "2.0"
                        }
                    },
                    "xml_base": "",
                    "xml_base_explicit": false,
                    "xml_lang": "",
                    "child": {
                        "": {
                            "channel": [{
                                "data": "\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n ",
                                "attribs": [],
                                "xml_base": "",
                                "xml_base_explicit": false,
                                "xml_lang": "",
                                "child": {
                                    "": {
                                        "title": [{
                                            "data": "Data name",
                                            "attribs": [],
                                            "xml_base": "",
                                            "xml_base_explicit": false,
                                            "xml_lang": ""
                                        }]
                                    }

                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }';

$json_decoded=json_decode($json,true);
print_r($json_decoded['child']['']);
?>
```